# Java in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: java, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, ide

Is there any way to manage/debug/compile Java projects in *Visual Studio 2010*?

Before you answer, please read [this topic](http://www.improve.dk/blog/2007/09/29/compiling-java-in-visual-studio).

Comment: I've found the NetBeans IDE to be somewhat similar in layout and approach to Visual Studio. It compiles and debugs Java code, and best of all, it's open source and free. Have you tried that as an option? http://netbeans.org/

Comment: I'm attached to Visual Studio too, but I don't try to write presentations for the boss with it.  Toolbox/tool/appropriate etc?

Comment: No. I don't expect the whole box, I didn't talk about Java.NET (which might be an idea as well), was just talking about syntax highlighting, project management, compile and debug etc.

Comment: 1) I am attached to VS 2) I never use JAVA 3) My question was 85% curiuocity rather than reality.

Comment: For those that compare VS to OSS NetBeans/Eclipse.  Keep in mind many of us (myself included) get VS free from our company.  For me, I code C# and Java.  So the cost of VS is moot and not relevant to the OP.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm a little late to the party, but it looks like someone has [started adding support](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bc561769-36ff-4a40-9504-e266e8706f93).  From the description, right now it only does syntax highlighting and basic navigation within a single file.  However, in the Q&A section the author mentions plans to add compilation and debugging support later in the year.

Comment: This plugin seems to force tabs, displayed as 4 chars, for indenting.  Not sure how to change it.

Answer (score 13):

The short answer - No.

The long answer - No, because the supposed intellisense support for Java that the blog entry referred to, in the question, relies on J# support. I believe it has been quite sometime since Microsoft has discontinued J# - VS2008 does not have it.

In the long run, you're better off learning how to use Eclipse/Netbeans/IntelliJ IDEA or any other IDE for the purpose of managing Java projects.

Answer (score 12):

Sure. Visual Studio works with any language so long as someone takes the time to write the plug-ins for it. Heck, Mainsoft has already added JVM debugging support to Visual Studio. They just don't support the language.

The only problem is YOU are going to have to be the one who writes it.

I won't lie to you. It won't be easy and fan-boys on both sides will hate you for it. But if you pull it off I can at least offer you some money to write about how you did it.

Comment: I am not planning to write one :) I was just wondering if there are other geek that did that adventure before

Answer (score 6):

No, although, I long for the day when VS might possibly support building Java applications. I don't think I have yet found an IDE as fully featured. Personally, if VS supported Java development, then I would trash my installation of Eclipse and Netbeans. ... so tired of wonky Java IDEs....

Comment: +1 and restarting NB 300 times per day due to Tomcat or some other piece causing out of memory problems.

Answer (score 5):

[Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/) is written in Java and developed in Visual Studio 2010, though it requires [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), an implementation of Java for Mono and the Microsoft .NET Framework.  Here are the [build instructions](http://trac.cyberduck.ch/browser/trunk/README.txt).

Answer (score 3):

C++ syntax highlighting looks pretty good for Java.  Turn this on in Options->Text Editor->File Extension.

- Extension: java
- Editor: Microsoft Visual C++

Now reopen a .java file and see pretty colors.

Answer (score 1):

I will advise to go for Eclipse, if you have to do at least 25% Java coding. Otherwise VS is good as well. But I like Eclipse for C++ as well as Java.

Answer (score 1):

A new plugin is currently being developed named IntegraStudio, 
aiming at full Java development under VS. It currently supports:

- IntelliSense for Java (comparable to standard C++ IntelliSense in VS)
- build with Ant or Maven
- direct Ant / Maven project view in Solution Explorer
- Java debugger with container visualization
- support for VS browsing features (Class View, Code definition, etc.)
- Class View works also for classes in JARs (including standard library)
- browsing Maven repositories
- JDK: 1.6 - 1.8

It uses standard JDK tools and targets the real Java platform (it
is not a .NET platform solution, as VJ# was).

At the moment of writing this, the IntegraStudio plugin is beta.

It does not yet contain advanced Eclipse features, however many
of them are in current roadmap (e.g. code refactorings and quick fixes).

You can find it on Visual Studio gallery:

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/588fb167-d18c-4e61-8aeb-30baeddb00da

The product official website is:

http://www.softerg.com/integra

Current docs (with large number of screenshots):

http://www.softerg.com/integra/docs/pages/is_intro.htm