# Unable to create a Java project in Visual Studio

Tags: java, file, visual-studio-2010, project, r.java-file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylka5.jpg)
I want to create a Java Project in Visual Studio but I am not able to find Java language in the list of languages given under Create a project

also I tried creating a java file but I cant find Java in that list of languages as well[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boyJU.png) and I had also installed JDK and verified with cmd command javac
So I would like to know if I have to install or modify any other thing to run java code in Visual Studio

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183226/java-in-visual-studio-2010). Your question is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Although there might be support for Java in Visual Studio, it is recommended to use [IntelliJ Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) due to it being designed from the ground up for Java as well as being created by JetBrains. The community build is fully featured for Java development with only a few features that mainly enterprises would need missing.

Comment: This may point the guy into a good direction but it still is just your opinion and also it does not answer the question.